# Convert given data into JSON format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need to convert this data to JSON format.

**Input:**

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      11725048
Current database:   
Current user:       cartadmin@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.2.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         1255 days 11 hours 7 min 4 sec

Threads: 11  Questions: 41743540705  Slow queries: 157520  Opens: 3668268  Flush tables: 47  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 384.832
```

```js
const input = `
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:     11725017
Current database:
Current user:       cartadmin@localhost
SSL:                Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:             MariaDB
Server version:     10.2.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:         127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:       latin1
Db     characterset:      latin1
Client characterset: utf8
Conn.  characterset: utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         1255 days 10 hours 56 min 30 sec

Threads: 11  Questions: 41743540474  Slow queries: 157520  Opens: 3668268  Flush tables: 47  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 384.834
`;

const lines = input.trim().split('\n');
const data = {};

let currentCategory = 'General'; // Default category

for (const line of lines) {
  const [key, ...values] = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
  const value = values.join(' ');

  if (key.endsWith(':')) {
    currentCategory = key.slice(0, -1);
    data[currentCategory] = {};
  } else {
    data[currentCategory][key] = value;
  }
}

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
console.log(jsonData);
```

But I'm not able to achieve an output in JSON format.

I tried executing the above program, but I am getting a JavaScript error.

Comment: Please include the expected output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want included in the output, but here you go :)

```js
const input = `
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:     11725017
Current database:
Current user:       cartadmin@localhost
SSL:                Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:             MariaDB
Server version:     10.2.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:         127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:       latin1
Db     characterset:      latin1
Client characterset: utf8
Conn.  characterset: utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         1255 days 10 hours 56 min 30 sec

Threads: 11  Questions: 41743540474  Slow queries: 157520  Opens: 3668268  Flush tables: 47  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 384.834
`;

const lines = input.trim().split('\n');
const lineCount = lines.length;
const data = {};

let currentCategory = 'General'; // Default category

for (let lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < lineCount; lineNumber++) {
  const string = lines[lineNumber].trim();
  
  if (string.startsWith('mysql') || string.trim() === '') {
    continue;
  }
  
  const kvArray = string.split(':');
  if (kvArray.length > 3) {
    const properties = string.split('  ');
    const propCount = properties.length;
    for (let index = 0; index < propCount; index++) {
      const subString = properties[index]
      const entry = subString.split(':').map(string => string.trim());
      data[entry[0]] = entry[1];
    }
  } else {
    const entry = string.split(':').map(string => string.trim());
    data[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  }
}

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
console.log(jsonData);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Connection id": "11725017",
  "Current database": "",
  "Current user": "cartadmin@localhost",
  "SSL": "Not in use",
  "Current pager": "stdout",
  "Using outfile": "''",
  "Using delimiter": ";",
  "Server": "MariaDB",
  "Server version": "10.2.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server",
  "Protocol version": "10",
  "Connection": "127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP",
  "Server characterset": "latin1",
  "Db     characterset": "latin1",
  "Client characterset": "utf8",
  "Conn.  characterset": "utf8",
  "TCP port": "3306",
  "Uptime": "1255 days 10 hours 56 min 30 sec",
  "Threads": "11",
  "Questions": "41743540474",
  "Slow queries": "157520",
  "Opens": "3668268",
  "Flush tables": "47",
  "Open tables": "512",
  "Queries per second avg": "384.834"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is likely due to an issue with how the data object is being constructed. The error message suggests that you are trying to set a property of an undefined object. It could be related to how you're handling the currentCategory and creating nested objects in the data structure.

Here's a modified version of your code that should work correctly and generate the desired JSON output:

```
 const input = `
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:     11725017
Current database:
Current user:       cartadmin@localhost
SSL:                Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:             MariaDB
Server version:     10.2.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:         127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:       latin1
Db     characterset:      latin1
Client characterset: utf8
Conn.  characterset: utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         1255 days 10 hours 56 min 30 sec

Threads: 11  Questions: 41743540474  Slow queries: 157520  Opens: 3668268  Flush tables: 47  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 384.834
`;
const lines = input.trim().split('\n');
const data = {};

let currentCategory = 'General'; // Default category

for (const line of lines) {
  const [key, ...values] = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
  const value = values.join(' ');

  if (key.endsWith(':')) {
    currentCategory = key.slice(0, -1);
    data[currentCategory] = {}; // Initialize an empty object for the category
  } else {
    if (!data[currentCategory]) {
      data[currentCategory] = {}; // Initialize the category if not done already
    }
    data[currentCategory][key] = value;
  }
}

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
console.log(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs and arrays. On the input, mysql object need to have ':' to define it as a key value pairs. So the input is in the wrong here.

Try this as an input

```
mysql:  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

    Connection id:     11725017
    Current database:
    Current user:       cartadmin@localhost
    SSL:                Not in use
    Current pager:      stdout
    Using outfile:      ''
    Using delimiter:    ;
    Server:             MariaDB
    Server version:     10.2.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
    Protocol version:   10
    Connection:         127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    Server characterset:       latin1
    Db     characterset:      latin1
    Client characterset: utf8
    Conn.  characterset: utf8
    TCP port:       3306
    Uptime:         1255 days 10 hours 56 min 30 sec

    Threads: 11  Questions: 41743540474  Slow queries: 157520  Opens: 3668268  Flush tables: 47  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 384.834
```

JSON convert with the input

```js
const input = `
mysql:  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:     11725017
Current database:
Current user:       cartadmin@localhost
SSL:                Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:             MariaDB
Server version:     10.2.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:   10
Connection:         127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:       latin1
Db     characterset:      latin1
Client characterset: utf8
Conn.  characterset: utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         1255 days 10 hours 56 min 30 sec

Threads: 11  Questions: 41743540474  Slow queries: 157520  Opens: 3668268  Flush tables: 47  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 384.834
`;

const lines = input.trim().split('\n');
const data = {};

let currentCategory = 'General'; // Default category

for (const line of lines) {
  const [key, ...values] = line.trim().split(/\s+/);
  const value = values.join(' ');

  if (key.endsWith(':')) {
    currentCategory = key.slice(0, -1);
    data[currentCategory] = {};
  } else {
    data[currentCategory][key] = value;
  }
}

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
console.log(jsonData);
```